# htaccess does not redirect to second top level folder

Tags: .htaccess

I use htaccess to decouple actual domain file names, so, for instance

```
RewriteRule   ^Contact/?$ /maindomain/contactus2001.php [NC,L]
```

Works just fine for the domain myxyzdomain.com, which is in a top level folder.

I have a second top level folder

```
/myotherdomain
```

and I want to do the same for its URLs like this:

```
RewriteRule   ^Information/?$ /myotherdomain/info20123.php [NC,L]
```

for the URL MyOtherDomain.com/Information

but that doesn't work. I get a "multiple choices" error but the error detail only shows one choice. The error says:

```
Multiple Choices
The document name you requested (/Info) could not be found on this server. However, we found documents with names similar to the one you requested.
Available documents:

/info20123.php (common basename)
```

Am I making some error or it is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

If you have .htaccess inside `myotherdomain` folder then you can use this rule with relative path in target that loads from current directory:

```
RewriteRule ^Information/?$ info20123.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: Can you show `VirtualHost` entry of `MyOtherDomain.com` in your question.

Comment: how would I do that?

Comment: If you don't know that then ask your server admins for this information